# Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'SELECT ISDATE(@P_Input)' to data type int

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
ALTER FUNCTION[dbo].[DateValidation]
(
@P_Input NVARCHAR(55)
)
RETURNS NVARCHAR(55)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @V_Results DATE
    DECLARE @V_Result INT
    DECLARE @V_ERROR NVARCHAR(MAX)
    set @V_Result='SELECT ISDATE(@P_Input)'
    IF @V_Result=1
    BEGIN
     SET @V_Results='SELECT CONVERT(P_Input,getDate(),2)'
      RETURN @V_Results
    END
    SET @V_ERROR ='NOT IN DATE FORMAT'
    RETURN @V_ERROR
END
GO
```

Comment: The error is telling you the problem here. `set @V_Result='SELECT ISDATE(@P_Input)'`; `'SELECT ISDATE(@P_Input)'` isn't a `int`, it's a literal `varchar`. Why, however, are you reinventing the wheel here? Why not just use `ISDATE` or (even better) `TRY_CONVERT`?

Comment: Also, please see this FAQ in regards to your comment: [Why shouldn't I assume I know who downvoted my post?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388686/why-shouldnt-i-assume-i-know-who-downvoted-my-post) Up/Down votes are anonymous and don't require other interactions on the post for the user to be able to use one. Just because Zhorov and I have interacted on the post doesn't mean that either of us are the (down)voters, for example.

Comment: i tried with varchar also but same error..i am trying to check whether given string is date type or not

Comment: It's not my downvote, @Mohammed Muntazim, I was searching for a similar soltion. And I usually try to help (with answers or/and comments). But, the actual reason for the error is the `implicit conversion`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ISDATE` unfortunately has issues because it does not necessarily look for a format that would convert via `CONVERT` or `CAST`. You may want to just use `TRY_CAST`.

```sql
CREATE OR ALTER FUNCTION dbo.DateValidation (
    @P_Input NVARCHAR(55)
)
RETURNS NVARCHAR(55)
AS
BEGIN
    RETURN ISNULL(CAST(TRY_CAST(@P_Input AS DATE) AS nvarchar(55)), N'NOT IN DATE FORMAT');
END;
```

I have no idea why you would want to do this, as you still end up with a `nvarchar`, and scalar functions can be slow. You are probably best off just using the following directly in whatever query you have

```sql
SELECT TRY_CONVERT(date, YourValue, 102)   -- 102 is the style number, pick the correct one
FROM ...
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all you are setting variable @V_Result with string (Command). If you need to make query dynamic then you should execute it:

```
EXEC ('SELECT ISDATE(@P_Input)')
```

But in your case, no need to create dynamic command, See the improved format of your function:

```
CREATE OR ALTER FUNCTION dbo.DateValidation (
    @P_Input NVARCHAR(55)
)
RETURNS NVARCHAR(55)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @V_Result NVARCHAR(55);

    IF (ISDATE(@P_Input) = 1)   
        SET @V_Result = CAST(@P_Input AS DATE)
    ELSE
        SET @V_Result = N'NOT IN DATE FORMAT';

    RETURN @V_Result;
END;
GO
```

Comment: this code also throws error "Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string"

Comment: I have test with string without date format and the output was the error message. Have you copied completely my answer? @MohammedMuntazim